# Best way to initialize a static list in a Python module

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, static

I have two Python modules: user.py and lib.py. lib.py contains certain functions that are written in the following way and are called from the user.py module:

```
def foo1():
    pass

def foo2():
    pass

def foo3():
    pass
```

Now I want to add a static list of strings in the lib.py module such that all the functions in lib.py module can use them. I want to strictly initialize the string list in the following way:

```
string_list = []
string_list.append('string1')
string_list.append('string2')
string_list.append('string3')
string_list.append('string4')
```

What is the most Pythonic way to achieve this? Would it be possible to do something like this that would work just fine?

```
string_list = []
string_list.append('string1')
string_list.append('string2')
string_list.append('string3')
string_list.append('string4')

def foo1():
        print string_list[0]

    def foo2():
        print string_list[1]

    def foo3():
        print string_list[2]
```

Comment: If you want to be Pythonic, make `string_list` an *argument* to `fooN`, etc. (or, even better, `def foo(string_list, n): print string_list[n]`).

Comment: You might want to call your variable `_string_list` instead of `string_list` to reduce the chance that a user overwrites it. http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private

Comment: I think `string_list` is global variable not static.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a Python list literal:

```
string_list = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4']
```

No need to call `list.append()` 4 times if all you are doing is create list of predetermined size and contents.

Comment: What if I want to use the append method rather than the list literal?

Comment: @MohammadRafayAleem: Go ahead, then do so. It's pointless, but it will work just fine. However, you asked for the most Pythonic method; why the verbosity when all you do is add strings that'll never change?

Comment: I agree with you on this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @MohammadRafayAleem `for i in range(1, 5): string_list.append("string{0}".format(i))`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `for i in range(4): string_list.append('string{}'.format(i + 1))`. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters haha you'd have saved a whole character, if not for the whitespace around `+`!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I have an irrational dislike for starting `range()` with `1` when you can use `+ 1` elsewhere instead...

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can also use composition ...

```
stringList = ['string'+str(i+1) for i in range(4)]
```